# C# Override Windows Shortcuts

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I searched over the internet and mostly over this site and I could not find a specific example. So, what I want to do is to override a Windows command (like `Windows` + `R` in this case to create a fake run box). I found many useful examples but only with one key at a time or some that involve just Alt, Ctrl and Shift.
In this one the Windows key will be disabled so I can reassign it but I want it to work in the background too, like this particular code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Structure contain information about low-level keyboard input event
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public Keys key;
        public int scanCode;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public IntPtr extra;
    }

    //System level functions to be used for hook and unhook keyboard input
    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int id, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hook);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hook, int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);

    //Declaring Global objects
    private IntPtr ptrHook;
    private LowLevelKeyboardProc objKeyboardProcess;

    private IntPtr CaptureKey(int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lp, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.RWin || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.LWin) // Disabling Windows keys
            {
                Opacity = 1;
                return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(ptrHook, nCode, wp, lp);
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get Current Module
        ProcessModule objCurrentModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
        //Assign callback function each time keyboard process
        objKeyboardProcess = new LowLevelKeyboardProc(CaptureKey);
        //Setting Hook of Keyboard Process for current module
        ptrHook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, objKeyboardProcess, GetModuleHandle(objCurrentModule.ModuleName), 0);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Opacity = 0;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't even understand 50% of this code. :/

Comment: If I'm not wrong this will only work when `Form1` will be focused?

Comment: The Windows keys are disabled everywhere and also do change the opacity (still everywhere, now).